# Create access policy to connect EC2 to Elasticsearch using IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I am trying to set up access from my EC2 to AWS Elastic search.

For now I just want to access Elastic search using the IP address of the EC2 instance. AWS instructions https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/set-access-control-for-amazon-elasticsearch-service/ say to use this javascript format, updating the IP address and resource.

QUESTIONS:

1. What do I put for the IP address? I associated an elastic IP address with my EC2. Do I use the elastic IP address or the original IP (private IP)?
2. What do I put for resource? Is this the EC2? I haven't associated a private domain with my EC2. I have an endpoint like ec2-1-10-0-10.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com.

```
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Sid": "",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
          },
          "Action": "es:*",
          "Condition": {
            "IpAddress": {
              "aws:SourceIp": [
                "111.222.333.444/32"
              ]
            }
          },
          "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-2:123456789012:domain/mydomain/*"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**What do I put for the IP address? I associated an elastic IP address with my EC2. Do I use the elastic IP address or the original IP (private IP)?**

- If your Elasticsearch is not within a VPC, then the ElasticSearch Service will be public, if this is the case you will need to put the public IP address of the instance (the EIP).
- If your Elasticsearch service is within a VPC, then it will be private and the IP you specify should be private.

**What do I put for resource? Is this the EC2? I haven't associated a private domain with my EC2. I have an endpoint like ec2-1-10-0-10.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com.**

This should the the Arn of the Elasticsearch domain in the format you specified

Comment: I don't know what is meant by Arn. Did I specify a format?

Comment: Arn is Amazon resource name an format is `arn:aws:es:us-west-2:123456789012:domain/mydomain/*` :)

Comment: And where do I find those numbers and the domain?

Comment: The numbers are your account id and `mydomain` is the name of your elasticsearch service domain. You can get this in the console